# Qt OPC-UA - Accessing Trend/Historical Data

Tags: qt, opc-ua, qtopcua

I'm using Qt 5.11.1 with Qt OPC Ua and the Open62541 backend to create an OPC Client application.

Is it at all possible to make a request for historical data with the Qt OPC UA module? E.g. Get the values for this variable (node) between these two times.

My server application has this functionality (FreeOpcUa) as I can set variables to be 'historized' and view previously stored values. But I cannot see an obvious solution to access this data easily on the client side.

At the moment I'm considering exposing a function on my server for each variable which would take in a start and end timestamp and manually gather the values and format them into a string or some object for the client to use.

Would anyone have any ideas or thoughts on a better way to do this?
I'm not overly familiar with OPC-UA or Qt so may just be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the OPC UA History Feature, both your OPC UA Client and Server shall supports the HistoryRead/HistoryWrite Services.

I don't know the status of the feature for your Server but for your Client (Open62541) those Services are not completely functionnal yet. Check the FEATURES document from their GitHub [here](https://github.com/open62541/open62541/blob/master/FEATURES.md)

Apparently those should be fully functionnal within the next 0.4 Release.

Answer (score 0):

The Freeopcua-Server supports historization (https://python-opcua.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html).

You have to enable historization per node (i.e. per variable you want to historize):

```
historize_node_data_change(node, period=datetime.timedelta(7), count=0)
```

> Start historizing supplied nodes
>
> Args:
>
> node: node or list of nodes that can be historized
> (variables/properties)
>
> period: time delta to store the history; older
> data will be deleted from the storage
>
> count: number of changes to
> store in the history

e.g. if you want to serve the history of the temperature you have to use "server.historize_node_data_change(Temp, period=datetime.timedelta(7), count=0)" (after the server was started):

[Python]:

```
from opcua import Server
from random import randint
import datetime
import time

server = Server()

server.set_endpoint("opc.tcp://192.168.178.20:443")
addspace = server.register_namespace("OPCUA_BurkhardsTemperatureSensor")

node = server.get_objects_node()

Param = node.add_object(addspace, "Thermometer_1")

Temp = Param.add_variable(addspace, "Temperature", 0)
Temp.set_writable()

Time = Param.add_variable(addspace, "Time", 0)
Time.set_writable()

SerialNr = Param.add_variable(addspace, "SerialNr.", "2323784628346")

server.start()

server.historize_node_data_change(Temp, period=datetime.timedelta(7), count=0)

while True:
    Temperature = randint (10,50)
    TIME = datetime.datetime.now()
    
    print (Temperature,TIME)

    Temp.set_value(Temperature)
    Time.set_value(TIME)
    
    time.sleep (2)
```